# Trouble saving a presentation in LibreOffice impress

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

I have a presentation in ppt format.

The size of the presentation is about 40MB. It consists of lots of images (there are about 120 slides and each slide contains about 15 images on an average).

When I configure slide show settings and try to save the presentation, the GUI hangs and the system needs to be forcefully turned off. The same thing happens every time. I suspect that it is the size of the presentation that accounts for such behavior. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 version.

I always open the LibreOffice Impress from GUI (from the launcher icon).

How can I get this fixed? I need to save the presentation with slide show settings.

Comment: How big are the images?  you need to try optimizing each image on size...

Comment: the images usually range from 20 to 120 KB.